# How to create separate two row in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when creating two rows in Bootstrap.

The first rows seem working incorrectly.

It only shows 1/2 content.

Like this picture:

[image]

I don't know why that.

You can see my example code:

```css
body {
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background: #FFF;
}

#crumbs ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-table;
}
#crumbs ul li {
  display: inline;
}
#crumbs ul li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  background: #F3F5FA;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 20px 0 60px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #8093A7;
}
#crumbs ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid #F3F5FA;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#crumbs ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
  display: none;
}

#crumbs ul li:last-child a {
  padding-right: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

#crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}

#crumbs ul li a:hover {
  background: #357DFD;
  color: #fff;
}

#crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #357DFD;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid color-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="crumbs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#1"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#2"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#3"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#4"><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Checkout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <ul id="filters" class="loaiduan clearfix">
                <li class="li-selected">
                    <h3>Mobile</h3>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div id="container" class="list">
                <article class="list--item">
                    <figure class="text-center">
                        <h5>Nokia N95</h5>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary responsive-width">View more</a>
                    </figure>
                </article>
              <article class="list--item">
                    <figure class="text-center">
                        <h5>Nokia E63</h5>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary responsive-width">View more</a>
                    </figure>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Or a link to my pen:

https://codepen.io/vanloc/pen/VMjwYQ

Comment: why creating **container** inside **row** ? and there is no **col-** class in your code, refer to the Documentation to know the good structure

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, I know the structure of Bootstrap.

Comment: so you have to correct your code and we don't use container as an ID

Comment: Ok, thanks, @TemaniAfif. I maintain code from older man coder in my company. So, I don't notice about that. Thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#crumbs ul li a:after` and `#crumbs ul li a:before` is set to a total height of 80px, (40 for the top of the arrow, 40 for the bottom), yet the height of `#crumbs ul li a` itself is 50px. Try setting that to 80px.

Answer (score 1):

I find out your problem, This problam Create your Custom Css, Just set height..

`#crumbs ul li a{
height: 82px;
}`

Comment: Thanks. @RedDwarfian was answered before.